# how te redirect to edit/delete data page after a record from table was deleted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-delete

i retrieve from the database a list with the ids and titles of some data and have for each an edit and delete link/button

after i click the delete for any of the data it works but i can t make it redirect me to the edit/delete page. here is the code for the table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Nume poveste</td>
    <td>edit</td>
    <td>delete</td>
</tr>
<?php
    foreach($results_stories as $data) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data->id_story . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data->title . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='edit_data.php?id=" . $data->id_story . "'>edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='delete_row.php?id=" . $data->id_story . "'>del</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    } 


    ?>
```

and here is the code for the delete.php:

```
try {
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// sql to delete a record
$query = $conn->query("DELETE FROM stories WHERE id_story = '$_GET[id]'");

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// use exec() because no results are returned
$stmt->bindParam(':id_story',  $data->id_story, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    header("Location: http://localhost/auth2/edit.php");
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Don't `echo "Record deleted successfully";` before the `header`, send the status to the next page. You can't output prior to the `header` function. Also this is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: ok, i moved the header up. still it works the same. let s say i delete record id 37. i get to a blank page http://localhost/auth2/delete_row.php?id=37. also i get no errors and no echo. and how is it open to sql injection if i have a prepare statement?

Comment: You aren't using the prepared statement at all. `$sql` is undefined, `$pdo` is undefined. Use some error reporting, see what is happening. Putting user input in SQL always opens you to SQL injections. No driver will know what is user input vs. what you (the developer) typed.

Comment: Side note, don't do this. `"DELETE FROM stories WHERE id_story = '$_GET[id]'"`. EDIT: Note what @chris85 says regarding prepared statements.

Comment: thanks guys for the tips. i'm learning along while developing this project and have many problems understanding how this stuff works. i replaced the "$query = $conn->query..." and "$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);" with "$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM stories WHERE id_story = '$_GET[id]'");" and now it works. much thanks again!

Comment: That's not really what I meant, that in no way protects your from SQL injections. You **neeeed** to use parameterized queries with prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Values don't go in the query. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29

Comment: so i have to use WHERE id_story = ':id_story'? if i do this i get the records deleted successfuly echo but the record isn t deleted actually. i will read more about it and hopefully make it work. this is for a school project and as long as it works its ok for me but i will try to impove if i can. thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly use prepared statements you should have:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM stories WHERE id_story = ?");
if($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the value. The `PDO` driver adds it to the query and quotes it as needed.

To resolve the header issue I'd do:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/auth2/edit.php?response=Record+deleted+successfully");
```

Then on `edit.php`:

```
if(!empty($_GET['response'])) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['response'], ENT_QUOTES);
}
```